# How do you float an image by the side of another image?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Hey guys I want my two #previews to float side by side. I have tried adding float:left but it doesn't work. At the moment they are just sitting on top of each other. All my code is below, thank you for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Juicy Designs</title>

<meta name="description" content="Juicy Designs">  

<meta name="author" content="Juicy Designs">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>  

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  

<![endif]--> 

<style>

body {
background: #F4F4F4;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
#logo {
background: url(logo.png);
width: 300px;
height: 75px;
margin: 70px 200px;
}
#container {
width: 1300px;
}
h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 29px;
color: #444;
}
p {
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
color: #444;
}
.line {
background: url(line.png);
width: 972px;
height: 1px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#previews {
border: 5px solid #FFF;
width: 300px;
margin: 50px 200px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"></div>

<div id="container">

<div class="line"></div>

<h2>Simple, clean & modern designs</h2>

<p>We create simple, clean and modern designs!</p>

<div class="line"></div>

<div id="previews"><img src="preview.jpg" /></div>

<div id="previews"><img src="preview.jpg" /></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Consider setting up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Next time please only post the relevant parts of your code. And set up  a demo somewhere like jsFiddle.

Comment: Id say that posting what they did was perfectly fine.  Also just as a note you shouldn't have two id's the same on two different elements.

Comment: I shall thank you :) Thank you John also, i've never been taught css or html taught myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Float them both to the left and it will work.  You'll also need to clear them then.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you set display: inline; DIVs are block level elements.

Comment: It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/gmRUG/

If you make them inline, then you do not need float. That's the whole point, kinda.

Comment: Ah, you are correct Zen. The default float value is left so no need to declare unless you're floating right.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:
a) DIVs are block-level. You would need to define them as display:inline; for float to work.
b) You should be using class instead of ID. An ID is supposed to appear once on a page only. Classes can appear as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

That's all:

```
<div id="previews">
    <img src="preview.jpg" style="float:left;" />
    <img src="preview.jpg" style="float:left;" />
</div>
```

You can also use this:

```
#previews img { 
    float:left;
} 

<div id="previews">
    <img src="preview.jpg" />
    <img src="preview.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Did it help to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en"><head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Juicy Designs</title>

<meta name="description" content="Juicy Designs">  

<meta name="author" content="Juicy Designs">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>  

<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  

<![endif]--> 

<style>body {background: #F4F4F4;font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;}#logo {background: url(logo.png);width: 300px;height: 75px;margin: 70px 200px;}#container {width: 1300px;}h2 {text-align: center;font-size: 29px;color: #444;}p {text-align: center;font-size: 22px;color: #444;}.line {background: url(line.png);width: 972px;height: 1px;margin: 0 auto;}#previews {border: 5px solid #FFF;width: 300px;display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:50px 100px;}</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="logo"></div>

<div id="container">

<div class="line"></div>

<h2>Simple, clean &amp; modern designs</h2>

<p>We create simple, clean and modern designs!</p>

<div class="line"></div>

<div id="previews"><img src="preview.jpg"></div>

<div id="previews"><img src="preview.jpg"></div>

</div>




</body></html>
```

You simply add `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` under the CSS for `#previews`. You will also need to reduce the amount of `horizontal margin` used for `#previews` because the width of the container is only 1300px.